# GeoFire SetLocation Not Working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am trying to save a location to geofire but not getting any response from console and in logs.

I have added the dependency in gradle files and created my database reference like this:

```
    DatabaseReference pickupRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(AppConstants.PICK_UP_REF);
    pickupRef.keepSynced(true);
```

and the string `AppConstants.PICK_UP_REF` equals `PickUpRef`. In my activity, I have done this:

```
Log.d(TAG, "UID in PUR:\t" + uid);
    GeoFire mGeoFire = new GeoFire(pickupRef.child(uid));

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mGeoFire.setLocation(uid, new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                if (error != null){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Write complete");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Write Failed:\t" + error.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

The oncompletionlistener never gets fired and nothing is updated in my database. Anyone else faced this problem or have I misconfigured it?

Here's my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jjoey.transportr"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
     buildTypes {
         release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
    }
 }

 dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'  
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.reginald:editspinner:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Probably unrelated but your 'onComplete' logic is backwards - you check for "not null" and so if it is null you then try access error.  So in other words if it was successful you'd get a null pointer exception.

Comment: @Andromeda please add grandle files too, thanks

Comment: @Andy, that's from the geofire docs

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos, check again

Comment: @Andromeda check my answer and tell me what happend

Comment: @Andromeda very well, you know best - but when error is null (the 'else' part) you then execute error.getMessage() which is a null-pointer access.  I'd guess you are catching exceptions higher up...

Comment: Yeah, the else part should throw NPE..thanks tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your dependencies like below in app grandle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.reginald:editspinner:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

And change in Project grandle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Comment: It's working, I realized the values being set were empty because of wrong variable names. I'll accept your answer though as no one else has tried in helping out. Thank you very much.